# How to align text after using transform property

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the text align properly after using transform property.
Below is my code

```
<p class="test1">Testing1</p>
<p class="test2">Testing2</p>
<p class="test3">Testing3</p>

.test1{
  transform: scaleX(0.8);
}
.test2{
  transform: scaleX(0.7);
}
```

[image]

This is my expected outcome. And I would like to make it suit with any devices. Can anyone help me with this issue. Thank you very much. Link below is my full code.
https://jsfiddle.net/83fe94na/

Comment: Why would you use scaling in text properties? If your goal is only for the font-size then I would recommend `vw` `%` in `font-size` properties. Good css conversion for the font-sizes. And if you  are using `div elements` or boxes. You can use scale property and put background colors in it to determine your scaling.. Putting text just for scaling is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`transform-origin: left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin).

```css
.test1{
  transform: scaleX(0.8);
  transform-origin: left;
}
.test2{
  transform: scaleX(0.7);
  transform-origin: left;
}
```

```html
<p class="test1">Testing1</p>
<p class="test2">Testing2</p>
<p class="test3">Testing3</p>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/barhatsor/bn0srj43/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change `scaleX` to `scaleY`: https://jsfiddle.net/0rzghfmb/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use `transform-origin:left:` for your `<p>...</p>` Tags

```
p{
  transform-origin: left;
}
.test1{
  transform: scaleX(0.8);
}
.test2{
  transform: scaleX(0.7);
}
```